# jquery date format like date(1) on linux

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, date, format

I want to format dates like `date(1)` on linux or `date()` in php does. I just found [this jQuery Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat), which has other date format strings. Is there a jQuery plugin or a js lib/function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [formatting support](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers) in the venerable [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library is pretty good.

JavaScript Date objects have a sufficiently rich API that constructing your own special-purpose formatter isn't very hard.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was searching for.